# Remove "s" on plural word for specific strings using regular expressions?

Tags: php, regex

I have some strings like "3 days ago", "6 hours ago", "9 minutes ago", and "12 seconds ago". I'm new to regular expressions, so I'm not sure how to go about matching the "s" before " ago" so I can strip it out if needed.

**Edit:** My code in case it can help someone else...

```
    function timeAgo ($timestamp) {
        $difference = time() - strtotime($timestamp);
        if ($difference > (60*60*24)) {
            $difference = round($difference/60/60/24) . " days ago";
        }
        else if ($difference > (60*60)) {
            $difference = round($difference/60/60) . " hours ago";
        }
        else if ($difference > 60) {
            $difference = round($difference/60) . " minutes ago";
        }
        else if ($difference > 0) {
            $difference = $difference . " seconds ago";
        }
        $int = filter_var($difference, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
        if ($int == 1) {
            $difference = preg_replace('/.(?= ago)/', '', $difference);
        }
        return $difference;
    }
```

Comment: First of all, why would you do that?  They are gramatically correct that way.  Secondly, there is really no blanket regex that can handle this because the rules of a plural word are more arbitrary than simply adding an S to the end of a word.  You would need to write a function to handle it properly.

Comment: hopefully you don't have `3 jiffies ago`, because it'd have to be converted to `3 jiffy`, not `3 jiffie`. "unpluralizing" something isn't as simple as just ripping off the `s`.

Comment: I'm going to do that to any that are "1". It's a small function, so those are the only options there will be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below regex to match `s` which was just before to `<space>ago`,

```
.(?= ago)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/tH2xX4/2)

Comment: And what about 'minutes', 'hours', etc.?

Comment: Thanks! `$string = "1 days ago";
$int = filter_var($string, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
if ($int == 1) { $string = preg_replace('/.(?= ago)/', '', $string);
}
echo $string;`